# $setPristine() not working only in ng-included document - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uGTGXyTpgfqKA2WhYVaR?p=preview)

**My target**

set *$setPristine()* in form submit callback function

**Its working here** localhost:3000/#/contact

```
        'content@root':{
            templateUrl: "views/contact.html",
            controller : "contactCtrl",
            controllerAs: "contact"
        }
```

**Not working here** :  Its open as a popup from *ng-included*

```
<div ng-if="contactShow" ng-include=" 'views/contact.html' " ng-controller="contactCtrl" class="contact-popup angular-animate"
```

error in console : "Error: a.test is undefined"  (test is a from name)
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uGTGXyTpgfqKA2WhYVaR?p=preview)